# Convert only floating point numbers to int in list python

Tags: python, list, list-comprehension

I am trying to turn any floating point number in the list 'codes' to an int.

```
codes = [890.0,'JFR']
codes = [int(c) for c in codes]
```

I am getting the error:

ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'JFR'

What I want the list 'codes' to be is:

```
[890,'JFR']
```

My question is how do I change only the floating point numbers to an int without getting the error?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You should try -

```
codes = [890.0,'JFR']
codes = [int(c) if isinstance(c, float) else c for c in codes]
```

Comment: Changed to using `isinstance`

Comment: this is not satisfying the requirement. you should have `int(c) if ... else c` instead.

Comment: Changed to accommodate that as well.

Comment: it seems you actually don't need the `or isinstance(c, int)` it works either way

Comment: I like this method because it is compact and neat thank you @AnandSKumar

Comment: Also, would advice you to accept answers if you find then satisfying, not just talking about this one, but in general , that help the community a lot.

Answer (score 2):

You could make a function that tries to convert to `int`, and if unsuccessful, returns the original value

```
def convert_to_int(x):
    try:
        return int(x)
    except ValueError:
        return x
```

Then call this function for each element in your list.

```
>>> codes = [890.0,'JFR']
>>> [convert_to_int(i) for i in codes]
[890, 'JFR']
```

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> conversions = [int, str]
>>> codes = [890.0, 'JFR']
>>> converted = [conversion(code)
                 for conversion, code in zip(conversions, codes)]

>>> converted
[890, 'JFR']
```